# One function to close a specified modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a lot of modal in my jsx file, so, I thought I need to create a function with if condition to close a specified modal:

Like this:

```
toggleModal = () => {
    if(d){
        this.setState({
            modalIsOpen:{
                Modal1: !this.state.modalIsOpen.Modal1,
            }
        });
    }

    if(d){
        this.setState({
            modalIsOpen:{
                Modal2: !this.state.modalIsOpen.Modal2,
            }
        });
    }

    console.log('click modal');
};
```

Ok, now, I don't know what a condition to pass to if-condition to let it know which modal to open / close.

Answer (score 1):

Nice and neat, you just need to pass in the name of the modal:

```
const handleCloseModal = name => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    modalIsOpen: {
      ...prevState.modalIsOpen,
      [name]: !prevState.modalIsOpen[name]
    }
  }));
}
```

And call it like so:

```
this.handleCloseModal('Modal1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a function that takes the name of the modal as an argument?

```
toggleModal = (modalName) => {
    const newState = {modalIsOpen: {}};
    newState.modalIsOpen[modalName] = !this.state.modalIsOpen[modalName];
    this.setState(newState);
    console.log('click modal');
};

...

toggleModal('Modal1');
```

Comment: onClick={() => this.toggleModal(Modal1)} ?

Comment: The argument passed should be a string, `'Modal1'` in your example.

Comment: Ok, but if I open the second modal, the first one closes. 
the first must remain open